# Mule/Anypoint and nested for each

Tags: mule

I'm trying to do a nested "for each" (one out of many) in my mule flow.
(The generated JAXB objects hierarchy is  Populations->Population->Person->Relations-Relation)
However, it seem that the object I expect to find in my second "for each" isn't there, the message says that payload is of integer type?
Is that the "counter"? How can I get to my nested collection of "Relations" in my second loop?

> ```
>     <foreach collection="#[payload.getPopulations().getPopulationpost()]" doc:name="For Each">
>         <logger.... />
>         <db:insert>
>         .....
>         </db:insert>
>         <foreach collection="#[payload.getPersonpost().getRelations().getRelation()]" doc:name="For Each">
>             <logger ..../>
>         </foreach>
>     </foreach>
> ```

Regards

*****EDIT******
I actually think the problem was that after my first "For Each" my payload consisted of the number of records inserted in the db. I solved it by setting my payload to a "originalPayload" variable before entering the first loop and then I chose to iterate through that one in the second "for Each" instead.

Answer (score 2):

foreach uses `counterVariableName` variable to keep the current iteration, if you nest two foreach there will be a conflict, try something like this:

```
<foreach collection="#[payload.getPopulations().getPopulationpost()]" doc:name="For Each">
    <logger.... />
    <db:insert>
    .....
    </db:insert>
    <foreach collection="#[payload.getPersonpost().getRelations().getRelation()]" counterVariableName="nestedCounter" doc:name="For Each">
        <logger ..../>
    </foreach>
</foreach>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, still get the same error though, the nested "For Each" expression fails with the message "Message payload is of type: Integer". Well it's not, it's my JAXB objects.. at least I thought so..